# Como achar a acurácia entre duas colunas de um data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho duas colunas do mesmo aquivo csv, uma aquilo que foi escrito e a segunda aquilo que deveria ter sido escrito. Ai tenho três dúvidas 1º Como encontro a Acurácia entre elas (ou seja quanto mais as linhas da coluna 1 for parecida com a mesma linha da coluna 2 melhor é a taxa de acerto acurácia), 2º como acho a linha com maior precisão e a com menor precisão, 3º como remover as linhas com menor taxa de acerto ?

```
import pandas as pd
relat_int = pd.read_csv
relat_int.head()
```

quando eu teno usar .score() aprece esse erro:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-d63a2ac83383> in <module>
      4 e = relat_int['Intenções Reais/Esperadas']
      5 
----> 6 relat_int.score(r, e)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'score'
```

Comment: Coloque um trecho do csv para facilitar o entendimento. O que você considera a acurácia entre duas colunas? Qual método `score` você quer usar, o DataFrame não possui esse método, por isso está recebendo esse erro.

Comment: Obrigado Damião.

Seria assim:

Coluna A   //    Coluna B
===========
Linha 1 da Coluna A = Bola     ///
Linha 1 da Coluna B = Sola    ///

Linha 2 da Coluna A = Rua    ///
Linha 2  da Coluna B = Rua  ///

Nesse caso o programa deveria perceber que a linha um está com resultado diferente e linha dois com resultado igual, ou seja a taxa de acerto(acurácia) é de 50%.

Expliquei melhor ? É que eu sou novo na programação....

Answer (score 0):

Considerando um dataframe no formato a seguir, conforme seu exemplo:

```
>>> df
   ColA  ColB
0  Bola  Sola
1   Rua   Rua
```

E você queira contar quantas linhas tem os valores das colunas A e B iguais, você poderia usar o [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html?highlight=sum#numpy.sum):

```
import numpy

total_iguais = numpy.sum(df['ColA'] == df['ColB'])
total = len(df)
acuracia = total_iguais / total

print(f'Acuracia: {acuracia}')
```

Agora caso queira saber quão próximas as duas palavras são (Bola e Sola são diferentes por apenas uma letra), você teria que adicionar alguma lógica de comparar cada caracter ou então usar algum algoritmo de similaridade, como o [SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher):

```
import difflib
s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'Bola', 'Sola')
print(s.ratio()) # 0.75
```